# IBM Watson Conversation & IBM Cloud Functions : User Input For Parameters

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-conversation, ibm-cloud-functions

I have already created a function in *IBM Cloud Functions*, but how would I implement the parameters from user input?

***What I'm trying to do is***

- For example: When a user types in "I need *product*" / "Buy *product* now" / Show me *products*. The ***product*** input is taken as a parameter and implements it into my Cloud Function, which displays all products that uses *product* as a keyword.
- The response text would get info from the Cloud Function return output (which is a JSON array)

  - (res.body.items[?].name)

---

**Example layout from IBM:**

```
{
    "context": {
      "variable_name" : "variable_value"
    },
    "actions": [
      {
        "name":"getProducts",
        "type":"client | server",
        "parameters": {
          "<parameter_name>":"<parameter_value>"
        },
        "result_variable": "<result_variable_name>",
        "credentials": "<reference_to_credentials>"
      }
    ],
    "output": {
      "text": "response text"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [full tutorial I wrote available in the IBM Cloud docs](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/tutorials/slack-chatbot-database-watson.html) which features IBM Cloud Functions and a backend database. The code is provided on GitHub in this repository: https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/slack-chatbot-database-watson/.

Here is the relevant part from the [workspace file](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/slack-chatbot-database-watson/blob/master/conversation-workspace.json) that shows how a parameter could be passed into the function:

```
{
      "type": "response_condition",
      "title": null,
      "output": {
        "text": {
          "values": []
        }
      },
      "actions": [
        {
          "name": "_/slackdemo/fetchEventByShortname",
          "type": "server",
          "parameters": {
            "eventname": [
              "<? $eventName.substring(1,$eventName.length()-1) ?>"
            ]
          },
          "credentials": "$private.icfcreds",
          "result_variable": "events"
        }
      ],
      "context": {
        "private": {}
      },
```

Later on, the result is presented, e.g., in this way:

````
"output": {
        "text": {
          "values": [
            "ok. Here is what I got:\n ```<? $events['result'] ?>```",
            "Data:\n ``` <? $events['data'] ?> ```"
          ],
          "selection_policy": "sequential"
        },
        "deleted": "<? context.remove('eventDateBegin') ?><? context.remove('eventDateEnd') ?> <? context.remove('queryPredicate') ?>"
      },
````

Some fancier formatting can be done, of course, by iterating over the result. [Some tricks are here](https://github.com/data-henrik/watson-conversation-variables/). The code also shows how to use a child node to process the result and to clear up context variables.

To obtain the parameter, in your case a product name or type, you would need to access either the [input string](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-tips.html#dialog-advanced) and find the part after "product". Another way is to use the beta feature "[contextual entity](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/entities.html#defining-contextual-entities)" which is designed for such cases.

Comment: Right now my Cloud Function already gives the product I need when a product name is passed into the parameters. Is there an easy way to just get a user input right after an Intent used? For example: ("I need _product_" / "Buy _product_") The intent would be "I need" or "buy," and Watson Conversation gets the String that is right after that Intent?

Comment: I added some more to the answer.