# IBM Watson Assistant: How to solve web_action error "Internal error: Content-type can not be retrieved."

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant, ibm-cloud-functions

I'm trying to connect IBM Cloud Functions with a Watson Assistant dialog as web_action. So I have specified web_action as following in watson dialog json editor.

```
"actions": [
    {
      "name": "rajesh@heltha.co_dev/default/callKinvey",
      "type": "web_action",
      "parameters": {
      },
      "credentials": "$private.mycredential",
      "result_variable": "context.my_input_returned"
    }
  ]
```

Now, the issue is while testing assistant I'm getting following error

**Internal error: Content-type can not be retrieved. (and there is 1 more error in the log)**

[image]

Following is my function that is created on IBM-cloud and enabled for **Web Action**:

```
/**
  *
  * main() will be run when you invoke this action
  *
  * @param Cloud Functions actions accept a single parameter, which must be a JSON object.
  *
  * @return The output of this action, which must be a JSON object.
  *
  */
function main(params) {
    return { message: 'Hello World' };
}
```

CURL of my function is:

```
curl -u API-KEY -X POST https://us-south.functions.cloud.ibm.com/api/v1/namespaces/rajesh@heltha.co_dev/actions/callKinvey?blocking=true
```

Comment: Please refer to the detailed answers to these very similar questions - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51357554/ibm-watson-conversation-ibm-cloud-functions-user-input-for-parameters

and https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/458474/cloud-functions-in-watson-assistant.html

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to solve this type of error is to append `.json` to your endpoint.