# Content-Type HTTP header missing in callout response. Watson

Tags: request, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I can't get information from an API in Watson Assistant with Webhooks.

[image]
Every time I try appears this error even tough I set the Content-Type.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the HTTP header is missing from the response of the webhook that is called by Assistant; the server that is running the webhook / the server that is called by Assistant to process the webhook.

See [How to solve web_action error "Internal error: Content-type cannot be retrieved"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55571788/ibm-watson-assistant-how-to-solve-web-action-error-internal-error-content-typ/58965485#58965485) which looks very similar. This was because the server called by Assistant to process the webhook was returning a response without the Content-Type header.

Answer (score 0):

I run into this issue today as I forgot to put `.json` to the end of the web action endpoint.

Instead of: https://LINK_TO_ACTION_NAME

It should be: https://LINK_TO_ACTION_NAME.json