# IBM Watson Assistant: Function daysBetween (start, end) not working

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I've tried using the  `daysBetween (start, end)` function in my bot. For some reason it's not working. The support documentation for IBM Watson Assistant said it supported the  `java.util.Date.`

Maybe I'm not using it right. Could you guys give me an example how to use the `daysBetween (start, end)` function within the  `java.util.Date` in the JSON dialog editor?

Comment: What is the code you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation, "You can use standard methods of the java.util.Date class"
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods#dialog-methods-dates-java-util-date

daysBetween is not a standard method of java.util.Date

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

You can achieve this by written a Cloud Function and calling it from Watson Assistant.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would there be a tutorial to show me how that?

Comment: You can check this thread. It has inputs as well as links with steps for implementation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51357554/ibm-watson-conversation-ibm-cloud-functions-user-input-for-parameters